# Spark DataFrame is not saved in Delta format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I want to save Spark DataFrame in Delta format to S3, however, for some reason, the data is not saved. I debugged all the processing steps there was data and right before saving it, I ran count on the DataFrame which returned 24 rows. But as soon as save is called no data appears in the resulting folder. What could be the reason for it?

This is how I save the data:

```
df
  .select(schema)
  .repartition(partitionKeys.map(new ColumnName(_)): _*)
  .sortWithinPartitions(sortByKeys.map(new ColumnName(_)): _*)
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .partitionBy(partitionKeys: _*)
  .mode(saveMode)
  .save("s3a://etl-qa/data_feed")
```

Comment: Can you replace `format` and `path` to their values so it's clear what you do? How do you check that _"no data appears in the resulting folder"_?

Comment: Also, what is `saveMode` ? Have you validated if writing works without repartition, sortWithinPartitions and partitionBy ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [quick start](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/quick-start.html) from Databricks that explains how to read and write from and to a delta lake.

If the Dataframe you are trying to save is called `df` you need to execute:

```
df.write.format("delta").save(s3path)
```

Comment: I've edited the code I tried and still the data is not saved and there are no errors in the program

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?